# Error publishing asp.net core app to azure

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, azure

I have an ASP.NET MVC Web application which I developed. Everything in the app works fine, I am using an sqlite database for storing data. After publishing it to azure, I can access the static pages but not the page where the website access is required to get the data. This is what I am getting:

Error.
An error occurred while processing your request.
Request ID: |4c0d1225-49f04498f224b900.

I am using ASP.NET Core 4.7, .NET core 3.1 and Visual Studio 2019 for mac 8.5.
I was following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/publish-to-azure-webapp-using-vs?view=aspnetcore-3.1) tutorial for publishing

Comment: I assume you are not using sqlite for the deployed app?

Comment: You could check the [logs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/troubleshoot-diagnostic-logs) for error details.

Comment: @Selthien I am using it for the local build only, it is not configured for development

Comment: @user7217806 Unfortunately I am using macOS, did not find any mac compatibility on that link

Comment: Maybe [this on](https://microsoft.github.io/AzureTipsAndTricks/blog/tip30.html) is more clear, you can e.g. use the `Log Stream` in the Azure Portal.